# Why when i print in superclass and extends this function in derived class it doesnt show a specific attribute in C++?

Tags: c++, class, printing, derived-class

I have this class with this enum :

```
class Artifact{
public:
    enum class artifactType{vase,jewelry,partialRelic,unknown};
...
```

In this class i've made this print function :

```
 void print(std::ostream& os){
        os<<"discoveryDate_:"<<discoveryDate_<<"-"<<"estimatedDateOfOrigin_:"<<estimatedDateOfOrigin_<<"-"<<"Enum that i dont know how to print:"<<"-----";
    }
```

first of all i dont know how to print this enum 
and second,i have 2 derived classes that inherits this class :

```
class GreekArtifact : public Artifact{
private:
    std::string nameOfGod_; //specific attribute 
}
```

and this print is not working

```
 void print(std::ostream& os) {
        Artifact::print(os);
        os <<" God:"<<nameOfGod_;
    }
```

I dont have error,but it just not showing the nameOfGod because in main i have created a list of artifacts and when i print it shows what is in Artifact class print ,not the specific attribute .I overloaded operator <<

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const std::list<Artifact>& b){
    for(auto it : b){
        it.print(os);
        os<<"\n";
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: All of the elements in `std::list<Artifact>` are of type `Artifact`, none are `GreekArtifact`. If you were going for polymorphism, then a) you need to hold a collection of (possibly smart) pointers, and b) you need to make the method `virtual`.

Comment: I have added in Artifact list more elements,of different types(GreekArtifact and EgipteanArtifact) and i have added virtual now at the print from superclass(Artifact) and nothing happend.

Comment: `std::list<Artifact>` cannot possibly hold a `GreekArtifact`. See also: [Object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

Comment: When you print a `enum` you by default get the integer value, if you want the symbolic name you have to write code yourself to map the value to a string.

Comment: Thank you Igor !

Comment: I tried doing this ```const char* ToString()
    {
        artifactType v;
        switch (v)
        {
            case artifactType::vase:   return "Vase";
            case artifactType ::partialRelic: return "partialRelic";
            case artifactType ::unknown:return "unknown";

        }
    }``` and this print : ```virtual void print(std::ostream& os){
        os<<"discoveryDate_:"<<discoveryDate_<<"-"<<"estimatedDateOfOrigin_:"<<estimatedDateOfOrigin_<<"-"<<"artifactType:"<<ToString()<<"-"<<"Condition:"<<ToStringC();
    }``` and it dispay strange characters.